# Cardano-wallet doesn't work after 1.35.3 update

Tags: wallet, cardano-node

After Vasil hard fork I did update the node with version 1.35.3 and also updated cardano-wallet to version v2022-08-16 which is suitable with 1.35.3

Although the node is running without any problem and its sync, cardano-wallet cannot connect to the node. This is the error:

```
[cardano-wallet.pools-engine:Info:46] [2022-09-27 13:46:10.26 UTC] Still in sync. Applied 17 blocks, 0 rollbacks in the last 300.000680263s. Current tip is [point 7dbc1268 at slot 72720072].
[cardano-wallet.ntp-client:Notice:308] [2022-09-27 13:50:50.26 UTC] ntp client experienced error Network.Socket.ByteString.sendManyTo: does not exist (Network is unreachable) when sending packet
[cardano-wallet.ntp-client:Notice:311] [2022-09-27 13:50:51.36 UTC] ntp client experienced timeout using IPv6 protocol
```

This is how I start the node:

```
 cardano-node run \
   --topology /home/centos/data/cardano/cardano-node-1.35.3/mainnet-topology.json \
   --database-path /home/centos/data/cardano/cardano-node-1.35.3/data \
   --socket-path /home/centos/data/cardano/cardano-node-1.35.3/data/node.socket \
   --host-addr 0.0.0.0 \
   --port 1919 \
   --config /home/centos/data/cardano/cardano-node-1.35.3/mainnet-config.json
```

Start cardano-wallet:

```
cardano-wallet serve \
      --port 1912 \
      --node-socket /home/centos/data/cardano/cardano-node-1.35.3/data/node.socket \
      --mainnet \
      --database /home/centos/data/cardano/cardano-node-1.35.3/data \
      --listen-address 0.0.0.0 \
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at my cardano-wallet running v2022-07-01 and saw the same notice (infact it's not an error but a notice).

Then I upgraded to v2022-08-16 and the notice went away.

So make sure you are running the latest version by running

```
cardano-wallet version
```

Also make sure you are referencing the right binary by running

```
whereis cardano-wallet
```

and using that path in your startup script

Comment: Did you delete the cardano-wallet directory and binary files and re-install all again?

Comment: nope, just upgraded the binary and restarted the binary!

Answer (score 0):

Your wallet may be actually connected, this line suggests that:

```
[cardano-wallet.pools-engine:Info:46] [2022-09-27 13:46:10.26 UTC] Still in sync. Applied 17 blocks, 0 rollbacks in the last 300.000680263s. Current tip is [point 7dbc1268 at slot 72720072].
```

Try if it responds with anything from GET network/information:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:1912/v2/network/information
```

Comment: Yes, it does and gives a "ready" response. However, I cannot send requests from outside even if I started the wallet with  `--listen-address 0.0.0.0 \` parameter.